# How group similar data in a single classes and reduce the error

Tags: algorithms, error-estimation, partitioning

I have vehicles gps information in my real time traffic application. Averaging that information I know the speed of every road at any time. The problem is that is too much data to send back to the devices, so I need a way to group that speed data into classes so I can to simplify the problem.

Right now I have something like this:

```
 road_id   time   speed
    1      09:00   45
    1      10:00   47
    1      11:00   38
    2      09:00   78
    2      10:00   77
    2      11:00   61
    3      09:00   51
    3      10:00   48
    3      11:00   41
```

As you can see:

- when close to 12pm more cars are in the roads so the speed decrease.
- road 1 and road 3 has a similar behavior probably both are regular street.
- road 2 is faster, maybe a highway.

So instead of save the speed for each road for each hour. I just want define general road behavior for the day and say that road is that type.

So I will have a table for `roads` and another for `road_type`

```
road_id      name        type_id
  1        A street         1
  2        B Highway        2
  3        C street         1

type_id  spd_09-10  spd_10-11 spd_11-12 ....
  1         50         50        40
  2         80         80        60
```

So I need an algorithm to create those types efficiently and reducing the error with the original data. I understand if I increase the number of types the error will decrease.

My guess is there is something already related to this problem just don't know how is called, and I don't want invent the wheel again.

Comment: Maybe [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) is a better place. However I think the first step is a deep data exploration, for example the exploration of [binning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning) can give you good information. As algorithm try to see [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and [Jenks natural breaks optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization)

Comment: @MauroVanzetto man too many places here. But I think k-means is the way to go. Thanks.